# How to connect wordpress install and cli docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, wp-cli

I am having great trouble with this, Trying to add wp cli to my wordpress installation with docker-compose but cant get it done as im getting an error when trying to connect the two in docker compose - IM getting an error about duplicate volumes.

Can you see what this is?

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./database/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb_assdf
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
  wordpress:
    image:  wordpress
    depends_on:
      - db
      - phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=admin
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=admin
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=mydb_assdf
      - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=adsf_
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
  wpcli:
    image: wordpress:cli
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
      - ./default/:/var/www/html/wp-content
    ports:
      - '1111:80'

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local
  wp_data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: You are trying to mount both the host directory `./wordpress` and the named volume `wp_data` on the path `/var/www/html` in the `wordpress` container.

Comment: Yep, Thats what the error says...